# Verify Domain In Apple Business Manager With AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, txt, apple-business-manager

I have set up an account up with Apple Business Manager, I have added a custom domain and it requires verification of domain ownership. My domain is registered with AWS and I can not find any documentation on how to do this. There are examples for Google Cloud and GoDaddy but non for AWS.